# Ordinal numbers and commas

Tags: commas, numbers

When writing large ordinal numbers, does one use commas? Is it `1,234th` or `1234th`?

Comment: In general, rewrite to avoid large ordinals, and many style guides (e,g MIT) say that you do not punctuate numbers with fewer than five figures (less than 10,000).

Comment: @marcellothearcane I am not sure it does. There might be exceptions for some ordinal numbers.

Comment: The short, and probably unhelpful answer is 'it depends'.  _...the use of commas varies somewhat depending on what style is used, what country you're in, and the specific context of your writing._ (From that previous question)

Comment: @marcellothearcane this is not a duplicate, the linked post does not address ordinal numbers.